# Create a while loop from function PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop, while-loop

i created a function to handle `While Loops`,  but the thing is, i can't make the while loop to work, it does not show a error message, and when i return the value it returns `user_id` forever.

here's what i have:

**Function:**

```
public function WhileQueries($sql) {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

**While Loop:**

```
$dbconn = new dbconnect;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

while($row= $dbconn->WhileQueries($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<br>".$row['user_id'];                  
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error or something? ...what if you try to `return $stmt->execute();` in your function?

Comment: you forgot to return `$stmt` in **WhileQueries**

Comment: "i can't make the while loop to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @Hackerman , When i return the value it loops forever  the user_id

Comment: This will run the prepare and the execute for every iteration, and then infinitely return the first row over and over again.

Comment: Put the call to `WhileQueries()` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i've commented, **WhileQueries** does not return anything so `$dbconn->WhileQueries($sql)` will throw excpetion like `call fetch method on a null variable`.

```
public function WhileQueries($sql) {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  //Add this
  return $stmt;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** Try this

```
$stmt = $dbconn->WhileQueries($sql);
while($row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<br>".$row['user_id'];                  
}
```